# Show page name in browser

Tags: page-template, title, get-the-title, wp-title

I am developing my first WP theme and would like to know how to display page name for every page/post instead of just "mysiteaddress.com"

How can I set that all my posts and pages show the tittle by default?

Comment: What code do you have now for your <title>?

Comment: I use <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title> on all my pages but I'm getting page tittle in this format >>About, >>Contact, etc... How to delete the >> signs?

Answer (score 0):

Your title is  being set by something in your theme or a plugin attaching to the `wp_title` filter. You can further filter this value or override it entirely by using the same hook and a different priority that executes later.

```
// add a filter at priority 999 so it will presumably run last
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'my_wp_title', 999 );
function my_wp_title( $title ){
    // use the post to do things like get_the_title( $post->ID );
    global $post;

    // $title will be the current title if you want to str_replace() or something
    $title = "The new title";

    // return the title
    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

This function can take different parameters> See [`wp_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title)

Answer (score 0):

The solution waas simple, just needed the right way of thinking about it.

I inserted the title code into the head of header.php instead of posting to every individual page template

```
<title><?php if (is_front_page() ) { bloginfo('name'); echo ' - ';  bloginfo('description'); } else {  wp_title(''); echo ' - '; bloginfo('name');  };?></title>
```